# mockmvc test when the request Url and view name are the same

Tags: java, spring, mockmvc

TestController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

      @RequestMapping(method = GET)
      public void test(Model model) {
      }

}
```

JunitTest：

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
public class Test2 {

  @Test
  public void testPage() throws Exception {
    TestController controller = new TestController();
    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();//.setSingleView(new InternalResourceView("/WEB-INF/views/test.jsp"))
    mockMvc.perform(get("/test"))
           .andExpect(view().name("test"));
  }

}
```

Run the JunitTest,there is a exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [test]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/test] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

I know I can use setSingleView,but I check the api of StandaloneMockMvcBuilder

```
public StandaloneMockMvcBuilder setViewResolvers(ViewResolver... resolvers)
Set up view resolution with the given ViewResolvers. If not set, an InternalResourceViewResolver is used by default.
```

It means InternalResourceViewResolver is used,so servlet will dispatch to "test.jsp" but not "/test",it should not be a circle,and it works well when I test in browser.Or StandaloneMockMvcBuilder doesn`t use any view resolver?

Comment: You need to return a string that is going to be the name of your view (In the controller method)

Comment: @Tiarê Balbi I add ' return "test" ' to the controller method,but the exception is the same

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring MVC, not the Springboot and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145408/use-mockmvc-outside-springboot-application) and setup successfully.